# How to replace char color in text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, replace, colors, char

I’m working with a typing game, and i want to change the color of letter in the text to red, only when i typed it correctly… like this: 
thanks in advance :-)

```
 string myString = txt.text;
    char[] myChars = myString.ToCharArray();


    foreach (char c in myChars)
    {
        txt.text = txt.text.Replace(c.ToString(), "<color=red>"+c+"</color>");
        break;
    }
```

[image]

[Updated Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3w4i.png)

Comment: You ought to show how you're drawing the text, since strings and chars don't have colour data.

Answer (score 4):

A whole UI [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) color is changed with `Text.color`:

```
public Text txt;

void Start()
{
    txt.color = Color.red;
}
```

It looks like you want to change individual character color. Unity supports [Rich Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html) which let's you change the font style, size and color of each character in a text. This means that enclosing the character with `<color=yourcolor>` and `</color>` will change the color.

```
public Text txt;

void Start()
{
    string goodText = "<color=red>G</color>ood";
    txt.text = goodText;
}
```

The character `G` will be red in the example above. All other character will be in their default color which is black. You can do this for all other characters as well.

In the example below, `Goo` will be red and the `d` will be black(default color).

```
string goodText = "<color=red>Goo</color>d";
```

Comment: i manage to change the color of the first char to red.. but the 2nd char is not and giving me output of something.. see my Updated output above..                                
                                                                                            
 <color=red><</color>color=red>F<color=red><</color>/color>EEL

Answer (score 1):

This should work, give it a try.

```
public UnityEngine.UI.Text myText;
 // Get index of character.
 int charIndex = myText.text.IndexOf ("S");
 // Replace text with color value for character.
 myText.text = myText.text.Replace (myText.text [charIndex].ToString (), "<color=#000000>" + myText.text [charIndex].ToString () + "</color>");
```